# Multiple storage of images and BLOB files in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, image, blob

I have a question about this query on inserting.

```
INSERT INTO BLOBTest
 (BLOBName, BLOBData)
 SELECT 'First test file', 
  BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(
   Bulk 'C:\temp\nextup.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB
```

It works great, but my question is how do I insert more than one image at a time?  I have a directory that has 1000+ images I need to insert.  They are all named in order (image0001, image0002, etc...)
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The following two links will provide you with the information that you need to do this.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/transactsql/thread/AEADA520-C989-4025-8CF3-085F0BFBD373

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic469199-5-1.aspx

Comment: Here is more complex example http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3632741/Upload-multiple-files-to-VarBinary-column-in-SQL-Server-2005.htm .Also you may need this too http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-enable-xpcmdshell-stored.html .